# confusion about exocyclic double bond

Tags: uv-vis-spectroscopy

[image]

I believe that there are only two exocyclic bonds in this structure. But in some text its mentioned as three. 
can someone clarify.

Comment: IMHO there are total zero exocyclic bonds.

Comment: I agree. Exocyclic means outside the ring structure; the double bonds are all within the ring structure

Comment: but, ring B has two exocyclic bonds

Comment: @RZZ …relative to that ring. yes, but they are still in another ring. It depends on the term *exocyclic bond* purpose and context.

Comment: ok. so for the purpose of calculating the Lambda max using woodward fieser rule. how many do you think are there?

Comment: @RZZ This is exactly a type of contextual info that should be included in the question text. There's an "edit" link below it (besides others).

Answer (score 1):

By definition (in Woodward-Fieser rule), an exocyclic double bond is a double bond where one of the $sp^2$ carbon atoms of the bond is a part of a ring, while the other $sp^2$ carbon of the bond is not a part of same ring (it could be a part of another ring).

If both the $sp^2$ carbon atoms of the double bond is part of the same ring, then it is called endocyclic double bond. From these definitions, you can understand that exocyclic would stand for a double bond outside the ring and endocyclic would stand for a double bond within the ring. Following examples would illustrate the definition:

[image]

Comment: yup!! agreed. so now according to this definition how many exocyclic double bonds are there in the structure i posted?

Comment: You may count it by yourself. You'd learn by that.

Comment: Three is the correct answer. One double bond is exocyclic to both cyclopentyl and cyclohexyl rings.